# How to sum numbers through a relationship table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of PRODUCTS

> ```
> +------------+---------------+---------------+
> | ProductCod |    unitPrice  | name          |
> +------------+---------------+---------------+
> |          1 |            30 | some          |
> |          2 |            20 | poor          |
> |          3 |            10 | example       |
> +------------+---------------+---------------+
> ```

Another of SALES (which I believe it's not needed) and some other to register a n..m relationship

> ```
> +------------+----------+------------+
> |   quantity | sellCode | productCod |
> +------------+----------+------------+
> |          3 |        1 |          1 |
> |          5 |        1 |          2 |
> |          4 |        2 |          2 |
> |          4 |        2 |          3 |
> |          4 |        2 |          3 |
> +------------+----------+------------+
> ```

How can I select a list of products and how many were sold at all registers?

I would like something like:

> ```
> +---------+------+
> |    name | sold |
> +---------+------+
> |    some |    3 |
> |    poor |    9 |
> | example |    8 |
> +---------+------+
> ```

Comment: Have you attempted something yet or would you like us to do it for you?

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is **not** a code writing service. Edit your question and show the SQL statement you have tried. With a rep of 34 you should already know this, but just in case, check out the links in my next comment for some helpful information.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a INNER JOIN is more exact here.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   products.name
 , SUM(sales.quantity) AS sold 
FROM 
 products
INNER JOIN 
 sales
USING(productCod)
GROUP BY 
 products.name
ORDER BY 
 products.ProductCod ASC
```

Or

```
SELECT 
   products.name
 , SUM(sales.quantity) AS sold 
FROM 
 products
INNER JOIN 
 sales
ON
  products.productCod = sales.productCod 
GROUP BY 
 products.name
ORDER BY 
 products.ProductCod ASC
```

**Results**

```
|    name | sold |
|---------|------|
|    some |    3 |
|    poor |    9 |
| example |    8 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10cd3e/5

Comment: Inner join would not include products which do not have any sales. OP asked "How can I select a list of products and how many were sold at all".

Comment: Yes which requires a `INNER JOIN` @CetinBasoz  not a `LEFT JOIN` a `LEFT JOIN` would translate into the question "Give me all products and how many were sold at all and i don't care if anny product was not sold at all"

Comment: Yes, LEFT join translates to that and that is exactly what the OP's question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.Name, sum(s.Quantity) as sold
from Products p
left join Sales s on p.ProductCod = s.ProductCod
group by p.ProductCod, p.Name;
```

What we are doing is first to join two tables using productCod common field. We are using LEFT join, because there might be products that are not sold at all yet. Then we sum the quantities grouping by productCod (and Name. We had to include it in the list because it is not an aggregation expression - and there is a single Name per productCod). This works right, because there is a 1 to many relation between products and sales. If there were a many to many relation then the result would be wrong.

EDIT: Check this [SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79caa/10) for a good formatting.